# MySQL Natural Ordering

Tags: mysql

**Background:**

I have the idea of a group which is a collection of items. Each item is defined by two properties: the group they belong to and their position with the group.

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE group (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
--other fields
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE items (
group_refid INT NOT NULL, --points to id in group table
group_pos SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
--other fields
PRIMARY KEY(group_refid, group_pos)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

So right now inserting items works  great. All I need to do is:

```
INSERT INTO items (group_refid) VALUES (1);
```

and the item will be appended to the end of the group. My issue comes up when I want to move one of the items. Moving an item should work as follows:

Example:

I have three items in positions 1,2,3, 4 but I want to move the one in position 3 to position 1.

Desired Result: 3,1,2,4 but their `group_pos` in the table should be 1,2,3,4 or 1,2,3,5

I want to do this so that the order of the elements (other than the one being moved) are preserved. Is there a good way to do this in one SQL statement? I would prefer one statement because I cannot use transactions so a one off statement is the only way to make it atomic other than using table locks.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Are you trying to create a `SELECT` query that orders by "items that are 3" first, and then shows the other items?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am trying to move an item that is already in the table to a different position. So either an insert or update or some other table writing wizardry.

Comment: *move* as in you want to move it in the database itself, or *move* as in you want to create a `SELECT` query using `ORDER BY` that lists the item first? I assume you want to keep the result forever? (so if you then move `2` to position 2, you'd get result `3,2,1,4`, right?)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Move it in the database so when I do `SELECT group_refid, group_pos FROM items WHERE group_refid= ORDER BY group_pos DESC` next time I get the item in the new desired position.

Comment: If you want to control the value of the group_pos, do not use a AUTO_INCREMENT but manage it using your own code.

Comment: @CedricSimon How would I do an insert so that the value is either 1 or 1 + max of `group_pos` for a certain `group_refid` without having possible race conditions? By that I mean I feel like I would have to use two statements to do that, a select then an insert which would have some time between them which could result in inconsistencies.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Use it inside a transaction to avoid inconsistencies

Comment: @CedricSimon You can't use transactions in MyISAM.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Then you will have to manage the update using a procedure, doing a reconstruction the values for group_pos for affected row and depending rows, leaving the auto_increment for new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, make your `group_pos` a float instead of smallint.
Try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d044/1) in the fiddle i set @position to 1 to take 2nd position, if you want it to be first in the list you can try setting it to 0.

```
SET @position = 1;
UPDATE items SET group_pos = 
(SELECT SUM(group_pos)/2 as newGroupPos FROM
   (SELECT 0 as group_pos,0 as rank
    UNION
    SELECT group_pos,@rank:=@rank+1 as rank FROM items,(SELECT @rank:=0)var
    WHERE group_refid=1
    ORDER BY group_pos
   )T1 WHERE rank IN (@position,@position+1)
)
WHERE group_refid=1 AND group_pos=3;
```

Comment: Oh now this is very interesting. I am going to mess around with this but this could be very well be a fantastic solution to this. I am not an expert on database things so it will take me a little bit to figure out what's even going on in that statement.

Comment: In the statement it's `select 0 as group_pos,0 as rank` to create a position at 0 rank. then the `SUM(group_pos)/2` creates a half way mark (the average) of group_pos. that way your position will be half way between position and (position+1).

Comment: What's with the `T1` and `var`? I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: T1 is just an alias for the inner SELECT, var is also an alias for the `(SELECT @rank:=0)` @rank is defaulted to zero, then as the SELECT group_pos,@rank:=@rank+1 happens it increment rank so that you have a rank number for each group_pos value ORDERED by `order by group_pos`

Comment: Is the select before the union just to set the values of `rank` and `group_pos` variables before the next one? Sorry this is a much, much more complicated query than I am used to.

Comment: no it's not to set but to return a row of rank of zero so that if your position is set to 0, you get a SUM of 0 and 1 returned so that the newgroupPos will be set to 0.5 which is before 1 which makes it first position

Comment: This will cover all cases for which you're not setting the position to be the last item in the order. If you want to set an item to be last you might have to do something like setting group_pos to be max(group_pos)+.5 or something

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 2 statements. Say you want to rearrange the items with `group_refid = 37` and specifically move item with `group_pos = 3` to the top (make it `=1`) and push all the others down.

First pull it into zero position:

```
UPDATE items
WHERE group_refid = 37
  AND group_pos = 3
SET group_pos = 0 ;             -- this is a temporary value
```

Then push all of them down:

```
UPDATE items
WHERE group_refid = 37
SET group_pos = group_pos + 1
ORDER BY group_refid, group_pos DESC ;      -- the order by is required
```

Comment: What if I wanted to move it to be second though? The move is not necessarily to the top is what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: That would be more tricky, for 2 reasons. First, you'd have to check/find where the second/third/whatever position is (there might be gaps in the numbers), then do it possibly in the reverse way than the above: first increase the counters, then move the item.

Comment: I would also be open to changes in the schema if necessary. This is just a design problem I have ran into using this schema, so if there is another way to make this work I would be all ears!

Comment: To tell the truth, this is really hard in MySQL, because of the way it handles updates. In Postgres, where the actions can be deferred, this would be much easier to implement - and with stricter rules (no gaps for example)

Comment: It seems weird though because it seems like this would be a common thing to do. I was hoping this is the kind of problem in a MySQL cookbook and there's a standard way of doing something like this but if not, I may have to look into alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I think chaining IF statements should work:

```
UPDATE items 
SET group_pos = 
    IF(group_pos = 3, 1, # sets 3 to 1
    # otherwise, increment if pos is less than 3
    IF(group_pos < 3, group_pos + 1, group_pos))
```

Obviously the condition `group_pos < 3` has to change if you're not moving it to the first position, e.g. to `BETWEEN 2 and 3` if you move it to second place.

The performance of this query will probably be heinous, though.

Comment: Note though, that this is what transactions are for; finding a way to use them would be better. Also there's no point in using auto increment for `group_pos`.

Comment: I would love to use transactions if I was using MyISAM. The point in using AUTO_INCREMENT for group_pos is to make inserts nice and easy. How else would you do the insert?

Comment: Also, this does not work by the way. Thank you for the attempt however.